# Test using Apple iOS Mail app

Tags: ios, email, appium, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Our server is running via emails, and we would like to write automated tests to manipulate mail apps and verify our service.

I try to use Appium and other frameworks, and later on realize that those testing frameworks are for people who own the app. We don't own any email app but would like to test using them.

Does someone know whether there is a way to test with iOS Apple mail app? I try to use the iOS simulator but mail is not there. And I don't see a way to launch the mail app via Appium.

Any hints are really appreciated! Thanks.

S

Comment: Did you ever manage to pull this off? In a similar situation.